# How to point the variable to specific memory location?

Tags: attributes

Point the variable to memory location ...

Hi,

I used to declare variable like this :

uint16_t storeVarBuffer[100] **attribute**((section(".DevOpt_Array")));

but now I want to put it inside structure like this

```
typedef struct _BMS_Var_Set_Obj_
{
    uint16_t    setVarBuffer[100];
    uint16_t    storeVarBuffer[100] __attribute__((section(".DevOpt_Array")));
    float       float_A;
    uint16_t    int_B;
    uint32_t    long_C;
    uint16_t    int_D;
    uint8_t     char_E;
} BMS_Var_Set_Obj;

typedef struct _UART_Vars_t_
{
    BLE_Var_Obj                 bleVarObj;
    BMS_Var_Obj                 bmsVarObj;
    BMS_Var_Set_Obj             bmsVarSetObj;
} UART_Vars_t;

typedef struct _UART_Vars_t_ *UARTHandle;

extern volatile UARTHandle uartHandle;;

extern volatile UART_Vars_t uartVars;
```

so that I can access like :

uint16_t var = uartHandle->bmsVarSetObj.storeVarBuffer[0];

but i have got the below erros :
line 132: error #2104: attribute "section" does not apply here

Danny